# How to call a function from parent class?

Tags: c++, oop, function

I want to call an inherited function of a superclass (parent class) in C++.
How is this possible?

```
class Patient{
protected:
  char* name;
public:
  void print() const;
}
class sickPatient: Patient{
  char* diagnose;
  void print() const;
}

void Patient:print() const
{
  cout << name;
}

void sickPatient::print() const
{
  inherited ??? // problem
  cout << diagnose;
}
```

Comment: What other classes derive from patient? If your answer is different than `"only healthyPatient"`, your design is wrong.

Answer (score 10):

```
void sickPatient::print() const
{
    Patient::print();
    cout << diagnose;
}
```

And also in case you want polymorphic behavior you have to make print `virtual` in base class:

```
class Patient
{
    char* name;
    virtual void print() const;
}
```

In that case you can write:

```
Patient *p = new sickPatient();
p->print(); // sickPatient::print() will be called now.
// In your case (without virtual) it would be Patient::print()
```